# Create a server in pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have a problem with postgresql, I want to connect my DB on RDS-Amazon but I don't find the option create server on PgAdmin 4.

I saw these tutorials:
https://adamtheautomator.com/rds-postgres/

But in my PGAdmin the situation is this:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try Register, Server. That will call up a dialog box. Choose the connections tab to enter server address\name, user, db and password :

[image]

Comment: ok thanks, but is the same stuf?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. the same stuff as what? If you call up the dialog as I said you will be able to use the connection details for your RDS Postgres server.